# Replace Div using Buttons on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am working on an app where I am thinking of changing the UI contents based on button inputs by a user. There can be a couple of buttons *prev* *next* *submit* . For all of these buttons, I plan to replace with contents from a JSON file. JSON file structure looks like :

```
{
    "steps": [
        {
        "step": "1",
        "code": "FNX"
        },
        {
        "step": "2",
        "code": "SMN"
        },
```

and so on. My current implementation is a mix and match of Plain JS/jQuery/HTML and I have made multiple pages like step1.html, step2.html and for every page, I read JSON file **onLoad** and replace the contents. However I have to create 100 pages if I plan on adding 100 steps. Was wondering if there is an easy approach for the same.

**The json file is in the root folder**
**Sample Code for my implementation**

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8887/steps.json', function(data) {
     var currentStep = 0; //represents level 1
     var divTxt = "<h3 style='text-align: center;' class='divTxt'>" + data.steps[currentStep].code + "</h3>";
     var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.steps[currentStep].step + "</td>"; 
     $(divTxtParent).appendTo(".divTxt");
```

Can someone suggest a better approach, something like where I load a single html page and use the buttons to move forwards/backword (based on current id's next and previous values)

Comment: Are you saying you have only one JSON file that contains the data for all of the steps?

Comment: Yes. Single file contains all data for steps. Right now I have approx 10 steps. But I am planning to make it more than that. Also Thanks for taking time to read the problem.

Comment: OK. Well, I've voted to close the question as "too broad" (sorry), because there are too many possible ways to implement this navigation, but in a general sense I'd be looking at having a `<div>` on the page that is a container for the content that needs to change, and a `showStep(stepNum)` function that knows how to update that `<div>` with details for the specified `stepNum` which it would get from the JSON similar to what you've already shown (except not re-requesting the JSON every time). Then you'd call that function from the *Next* and *Previous* buttons' click event handlers.

Comment: Let me try this approach. Pretty rusty in UI stuff. Thanks. @nnnnnn